# Count occurence of an element for a specific column for all lines

Tags: python, awk, count

I would like to know if there is an easy way to get the Nth element of each line quickly in python ?
For example:

```
2209002
2209009
9229222
2209002
2229022
9029222
2229922
2229922
0229929
```

For example, to know quickly for each column how many 0, 1, 2 and 9 ?
In my example the wanted output would be:

```
Column 1 = 0: 1 / 1: 0 / 2: 6 / 9: 2

Column 2 = 0: 1 / 1: 0 / 2: 8 / 9: 0

etc...
```

I was thinking doing it using readline() and using a looping while having variables with the count.. but I was thinking that maybe something (quicker ?) already exist that would work like the AWK command ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {m=split("0 1 2 9",val)} 
             {n=split($0,a,""); 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[i,a[i]]++} 
       END   {for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
                {printf "Column %d = ",j; 
                 for(k=1;k<=m;k++) printf "%d: %d %s",val[k],c[j,val[k]]+0,k==m?ORS:"/ "}}' file

Column 1 = 0: 1 / 1: 0 / 2: 6 / 9: 2
Column 2 = 0: 1 / 1: 0 / 2: 8 / 9: 0
Column 3 = 0: 3 / 1: 0 / 2: 6 / 9: 0
Column 4 = 0: 0 / 1: 0 / 2: 0 / 9: 9
Column 5 = 0: 4 / 1: 0 / 2: 2 / 9: 3
Column 6 = 0: 3 / 1: 0 / 2: 6 / 9: 0
Column 7 = 0: 0 / 1: 0 / 2: 7 / 9: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use loops and a hash.  Its easy to understand and straightforward to implement.  To me, unless the real problem is larger, there would no benefit to using a more complex solution

```
input = """
2209002
2209009
9229222
2209002
2229022
9029222
2229922
2229922
0229929
"""

cols = {};
for line in input.split('\n'):
    for i,s in enumerate(line):
        if not cols.get(s):
            cols[s] = 0
        cols[s] += 1
```